# How can I adjust the distance and offset of a button next to a text in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[This](https://jsfiddle.net/o0fq9q5a/) is an example, where the button is not alligned with the text properly, it look like it appears somehow lower. Is there any way I can precisely offset the button to the right and up some distance?

The code is as follows:

```
                <div class="content">
                        <h2>Shows</h2>
                                                                                    <!-- Unordered List -->
                                    <header><h3>
                                        <ul class="alt">
                                        <li><b>Lelelele: </b>25.10, 29.11, 7.12

                                            <form style=display:inline action="/your-server-side-code" method="POST">
                                              <script
                                                src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
                                                data-key=""
                                                data-amount="1000"
                                                data-name=""
                                                data-description="Widget"
                                                data-image="https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png" <!-- Image that shows up when clicking on pay with card-->
                                                data-locale="auto"
                                                data-zip-code="true"
                                                data-currency="eur">
                                              </script>
                                              </form>
                                              </li>

                                            <li><b>Lalalala: </b>24.10, 28.11, 30.1</li>
                                            <li>more info here</li>
                                            <li>How about:</li>
                                            <a href="" class="button special">Le</a>                    <a href="" class="button">La</a>
                                        </ul>
                                        <ul class="actions">
                                        </ul>
                                    </header></h3>

                        </p>
                    </div>
```

What would be some fields to change in the class of the button in css to fix this?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can put following css to your button class

```
.stripe-button-el {
    height: 32px;
    margin-left:10px
```

See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/malik_nasir/o0fq9q5a/4/)

Comment: margin-left worked to separate the button from the text, but margin-top/bottom only created a space on top and below the button. Is there any way to position the button up or down? It always stays in the same location (height only increases the size of the button itself, not its position)

Comment: You can move the button under text by setting display:block property

.stripe-button-el {    
height: 32px;    
margin-left:0;    
display:block;

Comment: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/malik_nasir/o0fq9q5a/5/)

.stripe-button-el 
{ 
height: 32px; 
margin-left:0; 
display:block !important